# How to prove that two equations in complex numbers have no solution in common?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

So my complex numbers are:

$$r_1^n = 1+i$$
$$r_2^m = 2-i$$

$$r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb{C} \quad;\quad n,m \in \mathbb{N}$$

I wrote down the general $z^n=r^n(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta))$ formula for these, but I don't know what to do after this step to prove these two equations don't have any common solution.

Comment: Have you tried matching real and imaginary parts?

Comment: You can start by comparing absolute values of these numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ are such that

$$
z^n = 1 + i \\
z^m = 2 - i
$$

for some complex number $z = r e^{i\theta}$. Note that $n > 0$ and $m > 0$. Taking the absolute value of both equations we get

$$
r^n = \sqrt{2} \\
r^m = \sqrt{5}
$$

and so

$$
r^{nm} = \sqrt{2^m} \\
r^{nm} = \sqrt{5^n}.
$$

But this implies that

$$
2^m = 5^n
$$

which is impossible since the left hand side is even and the right hand side is odd.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it's a super simple question but I didn't get one point. How can we directly say "$r^n=\sqrt{2}$"? I mean, yes I know the way to take an absolute value but I just couldn't understand why we didn't exponentiate $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Begin with $z^n = 1 + i$. If these two numbers are equal, then their absolute values are also equal. Therefore, $|z^n| = |1 + i|$. Now, let's compute both sides. On the left: since $z = re^{i\theta}$, we have $|z| = r$ and $|z^n| = r^n$. On the right: $|1 + i| = \sqrt{2}$. Putting it all together we get $r^n = \sqrt{2}$. We didn't exponentiate $\sqrt{2}$, because it corresponds to the absolute value of the right hand side of the original equation and that is not raised to any power.

Comment: OK, I understand that one. Now I have one last question. Did we ever actually used the $z=re^{i\theta}$ formula in this solution, if yes, where and how? Sorry for the silly questions but I'm a newbie on this subject.

Comment: Writing $z$ in the polar form $re^{i\theta}$ was really just a way to introduce $r$ which I could use for the absolute value. I may as well have just written $r := |z|$ and drop $z = er^{i\theta}$. Note that this is a fairly common practice, though :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assume that there exists some $z$ for which $z^n=1+i$ and $z^m=2-i$ for some integers $m$ and $n$. You're right to think about converting between rectangular and polar, but in this case it's polar form that's useful:
$$1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{i\theta_1},\ \ 2-i=\sqrt{5}e^{i\theta_2}.$$
(I haven't bothered to find $\theta_1$ or $\theta_2$, since they happen not to be relevant). So, by comparing magnitudes,
$$|z|=2^{\frac{1}{2n}}=5^{\frac{1}{2m}}.$$
Can you show that this can never happen?

Answer (score 1):

$r_1=(1+i)^{1/n}$ and and $r_2=(2-i)^{1/m}$  implies $|r_1|=\sqrt{2}^{1/n}$ and $|r_2|=\sqrt{5}^{1/m}.$. Therefore $|r_1|\neq |r_2|$ for any values of $m,n$ which intern implies that  $r_1\neq r_2$ for any values of $m,n.$